# Why does this Swift playground show a different number of executions when both versions have the same behavior?

Tags: swift

I use the map function to traverse the same array, is not the same, why the number of traverse is not the same?

[image: playground image]

---

Here's the code:

```
let list = ["1", "2", "3"]

let arr = list.map { $0 + $0 }

let mArr = list.map { str in
    return str + str
}

print(arr)
print(mArr)
```

Comment: An image of your code is useless to us. See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of many reasons why you should NOT post code as images. Your code needs to be here, as text and properly formatted, in the question itself.

Comment: It's not that simple. Xcode provides no good way to capture both the playground's code and the results column together as text. New users should be treated with kindness, not disdain. Somehow, I was able to answer this user's question based on the “useless” image.

Answer (score 5):

The call to `map` counts as one execution, and each execution of the statement inside the closure counts as one execution.

In the first case, the call to `map` is on the same line as the statement in the closure, so Xcode shows the total number of times anything on that line was executed, which is 4 times: 1 execution of `map` plus 3 executions of the statement inside the closure.

In the second case, the call to `map` is on a separate line from the statement in the closure. Since that call to `map` is executed only once, and nothing else is executed on that line, Xcode shows what `map` returns: the list `["11", "22", "33"]`. The statement inside the closure is executed 3 times, so Xcode shows the number of times it is executed.